# Import error lxml when working with IronPython

Tags: python-2.7, lxml, ironpython

I am parsing a xml file using lxml module  on python successfully. When run the same code on IronPython it got an error like `ImportError: cannot import etree from lxml`. I am already install the lxml module.Any idea? Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you amend your code in IronPython to do this (as recommended in the [`lxml` tutorial](https://lxml.de/tutorial.html)).

```
try:
  from lxml import etree
  print("running with lxml.etree")
except ImportError:
  try:
    # Python 2.5
    import xml.etree.cElementTree as etree
    print("running with cElementTree on Python 2.5+")
  except ImportError:
    try:
      # Python 2.5
      import xml.etree.ElementTree as etree
      print("running with ElementTree on Python 2.5+")
    except ImportError:
      try:
        # normal cElementTree install
        import cElementTree as etree
        print("running with cElementTree")
      except ImportError:
        try:
          # normal ElementTree install
          import elementtree.ElementTree as etree
          print("running with ElementTree")
        except ImportError:
          print("Failed to import ElementTree from any known place")
```

This probably won't solve your problem but it may make it clearer where it is.

Comment: Thanks for your time. I got my answer from your code. Thank you so much..